# Searching for a substring in a dataframe and replacing it

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a condition where spurious data is created and I am trying to clean it.

eg...

```
www.one@foxturn.com/!ut/5 #RealLink
www.one@foxturn.com/ut1/5_RTFDEERERTGFEFD # System adds junks to it
www.one@foxturn.com/ut1/5_dvkerfddfrejermsdkasmf # System adds junks to it
```

I am trying to clean this up by dropping everything after `!ut`

So far I have tried :

```
SPA_MX = Mexico['Page URL'].str.startswith("http://www.www.one@foxturn.com/ut1")
```

but this returns a boolean.

I would like advise on the most efficient way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `apply` on the column and then use `find` to return the index of the pattern and slice the str if found:

```
In[69]:

df['url'].apply(lambda x: x[:x.find('!ut') + 3] if x.find('!ut') != -1 else x)

Out[69]: 
0                             www.one@foxturn.com/!ut
1           www.one@foxturn.com/ut1/5_RTFDEERERTGFEFD
2    www.one@foxturn.com/ut1/5_dvkerfddfrejermsdkasmf
Name: url, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for this,..I would like to keep !ut but drop everything after this..how can I achieve this? ie...all the links looking the same.

Comment: See update, unfortunately as the position is variable I don't think there is a nice way of doing this without using `apply` as you can't do variable length slicing on a string column

Answer (score 1):

```
my_string="www.one@foxturn.com/!ut/5"
final =  my_string.split("!ut")[0]
```

**output:**

> www.one@foxturn.com/